# How to remove duplicate pairs in a List

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I got a List with pairs of integers. How do I remove pairs if they're duplicates? Distinct wont work cause the pair could be (2, 1) instead of (1, 2).

My list looks like this:

```
1, 2
2, 3
3, 1
3, 2
2, 4
4, 3
```

... I don't need (2, 3) and (3, 2)

I made a `public struct FaceLine` with `public int A` and `B`, then `var faceline = new List<FaceLine>();`.

I'm  new to C# and lost.

Comment: What kind of list stores a pair of integers? A `List<Tuple<int,int>>`?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: please add your code, how do you store pairs in a list?

Comment: I made a public struct face line with public int a and b then List<faceline> Faceline = new List<faceline>();

Comment: Faceline.Add(new faceline { a = int, b = int });

Comment: Better if you edit your question & add the code in your comments.

Comment: `Distinct` would work with `Tuple<int,int>` or value tuples, or a custom class that overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` properly.  On the other hand if you use an array or list then I'd suggest switch to on of the previous methods instead.

Comment: With a custom class you have 3 options.  Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` based on the 2 values (if it makes sense for the class).  Create an `IEqualityComparer<T>` you can pass to `Distinct` and other methods and classes.  Or just write code that will keep track of what you've seen in a couple `HashSet<Tuple<int,int>>` that keep track of both orders.

Comment: Can you clear up if you need the results to not contain either of (2,3) and (3,2) or just contain one of them?  `Distinct` would keep one, whereas you need Tim's solution to remove both.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a custom `IEqualityComparer<FaceLine>`:

```
public class UnorderedFacelineComparer : IEqualityComparer<FaceLine>
{
    public bool Equals(FaceLine x, FaceLine y)
    {
        int x1 = Math.Min(x.A, x.B);
        int x2 = Math.Max(x.A, x.B);
        int y1 = Math.Min(y.A, y.B);
        int y2 = Math.Max(y.A, y.B);
        return x1 == y1 && x2 == y2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FaceLine obj)
    {
        return obj.A ^ obj.B;
    }
}
```

Then the query was very simple:

```
var comparer = new UnorderedFacelineComparer();
List<FaceLine> nonDupList = faceLine
    .GroupBy(fl => fl, comparer)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

If you wanted to keep one of the duplicates you just need to remove the `Where`:

```
List<FaceLine> nonDupList = faceLine
    .GroupBy(fl => fl, comparer)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: why `g.First()`? does not `.Where(g => g.Count() == 1)` covers it?

Comment: @styx: not if the result should be again a `List<FaceLine>` where all duplicates are removed. After `.Where(g => g.Count() == 1).ToList()` we get a `List<System.Linq.IGrouping<FaceLine, FaceLine>>`. The query doesn't know that the groups contain only one and we want only that, therefore we need the `First`.

Comment: How do you know that "we get a...xxx", how do you know where the query will resolve? What kinda magic can help someone like me know that? That's really helpful.

Comment: @AussieJoe: at least visual studio, rider and monodevelop show the return type of every method when you hover over one.

Comment: @AussieJoe: If all else fails just look at the documentation. eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334(v=vs.110).aspx tells you what the `GroupBy` returns, then repeat for each method in the chain. After a while you get used to it (and it helps that they all make sense if you think about it hard enough).

Comment: @Rawcal that's the way I do it already, and was wondering if there was more. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq :

```
List<List<int>> data = new List<List<int>>() {
    new List<int>() {1, 2},
    new List<int>() {2, 3},
    new List<int>() {3, 1},
    new List<int>() {3, 2},
    new List<int>() {2, 4},
    new List<int>() {4, 3}
};

List<List<int>> results = 
  data.Select(x => (x.First() < x.Last()) 
     ? new { first = x.First(), last = x.Last() } 
     : new { first = x.Last(), last = x.First() })
  .GroupBy(x => x)
  .Select(x => new List<int>() { x.First().first, x.First().last }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy using the common `DistinctBy` Linq extension ([available via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy/)) you can do this fairly simply like so:

```
var result = list.DistinctBy(x => (x.A > x.B) ? (x.A, x.B) : (x.B, x.A));
```

Sample console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MoreLinq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Test
    {
        public Test(int a, int b)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
        }

        public readonly int A;
        public readonly int B;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"A={A}, B={B}";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test(1, 2),
                new Test(2, 3),
                new Test(3, 1),
                new Test(3, 2),
                new Test(2, 4),
                new Test(4, 3)
            };

            var result = list.DistinctBy(x => (x.A > x.B) ? (x.A, x.B) : (x.B, x.A));

            foreach (var item in result)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form a set of sets and you get the functionality for free (each smaller set contains exactly two integers).

Comment: It's a good approach, but some notes about .net classes (such as `HashSet<T>`) would be useful.

Comment: I fell like this is way too vague to be a good answer.  Please include some example code.